# Proving Nyquist Sampling Theorem for Strictly Band Limited Signals (Whittaker Shannon Interpolation Formula)

Tags: signal-analysis, sampling, interpolation, nyquist, reconstruction

I understand that the Nyquist sampling theorem dictates that the minimum  sampling frequency, $f_s$, be s.t. $f_s > 2B$, where $ B $, is the bandwidth of the signal. I have read the explanation for what happens when the input signal contains an impulse/non zero ferquency spectrum at $f_s = f_m$. But is there any way to do a mathematical proof that sampling at $f_s = 2B$ works when the signal is strictly bandlimited.

A little background : This is a HW problem

[image]

The given hint was to use the fact that "one way to interpret Nyquist
Sampling theorem is to note that any bandlimited signal can be represented as a superposition of bandlimited signals that are orthogonal to each other."

Comment: Google “generalized sampling theorem”. There is a paper by Papoulis

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz I think you mean [this Papoulis paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/TCS.1977.1084284) (paywall).

Comment: I added a solution of the Sampling Theorem built on Super Position of Bandlimited Signals.

Comment: what does $f_m$ mean?

Comment: @RJ_DSP, Could you please review my answer? If something missing, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

## Approaching The Sampling Theorem as Inner Product Space

### Preface

There are many ways to derive the [Nyquist Shannon Sampling Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) with the constraint on the sampling frequency being 2 times the [Nyquist Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency).
The classic derivation uses the summation of sampled series with [Poisson Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).

Let's introduce different approach which is more similar to function analysis - Building an orthogonal space and using projection for analysis and synthesis.

### Forming Orthonormal Basis

In this section we'll define an orthonormal base and derive the decomposition and composition process.

#### Definitions

First one should define the space of *Band Limited Functions*. The space of *Band Limited Functions* is defined by:

$$ \mathcal{B}_{ {W}_{s} } = \left\{ f \left( x \right) \mid F \left( \omega \right) = \mathscr{F} \left\{ f \left( x \right) \right\}, \; F \left( \omega \right) = 0, \; \forall \, \left| \omega \right| > {W}_{s} \right\} $$

In words, it means that for each function $ f \left( x \right) \in \mathcal{B}_{ {W}_{s} }$ its fourier transform $ F \left( \omega \right) = \mathscr{F} \left\{ f \left( x \right) \right\} $ vanishes for frequencies $ \left| \omega \right| > {W}_{s} $.

The inner product in this space is given by:

$$ \langle f \left( x \right), g \left( x \right) \rangle = \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f \left( x \right) g \left( x \right) dx, \; T = \frac{2 \pi}{ {W}_{s} } $$

One could easily show that this is a indeed an inner product space with valid inner product.

The main claim is the orthonormal basis of this space is given by:

$$ f \left( x \right) = \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) $$

Where $ \operatorname{sinc} \left( x \right) $ is the [Normalized Sinc Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) given by $ \operatorname{sinc} \left( x \right) = \frac{ \sin(\pi x) }{ \pi x } $.
The basis functions are parameterized by the parameter $ n $. Basically we have shifted and scaled function as the basis.

#### Proof of The Orthonormal Property

One must show the orthonormal property of the basis under the defined inner product:

$$ \begin{aligned}
\langle f \left( x \right), g \left( x \right) \rangle & = \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f \left( x \right) g \left( x \right) dx = \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - m T }{T} \right) dx && \text{} \\
& \overset{1}{=} \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} T \, \Pi \left( \frac{ \omega }{ {W}_{s} } \right) {e}^{-j \omega n T} {e}^{j \omega t} d\omega \right) \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - m T }{T} \right) dx && \text{} \\
& \overset{2}{=} \frac{1}{T} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} T \, \Pi \left( \frac{\omega}{ {W}_{s} } \right) {e}^{-j \omega n T} \left( \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} {e}^{j \omega x} \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{x - m T}{T} \right) dx \right) d\omega && \text{} \\
& \overset{3}{=} \frac{1}{T} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} T \, \Pi \left( \frac{\omega}{ {W}_{s} } \right) {e}^{-j \omega n T} T \, \Pi \left( \frac{-\omega}{ {W}_{s} } \right) {e}^{j \omega m T} d\omega && \text{} \\
& \overset{4}{=} \frac{T}{2 \pi} \int_{ - \frac{ {W}_{s} }{2} }^{ \frac{ {W}_{s} }{2} } {e}^{j \omega \left( m - n \right) T} d\omega && \text{} \\
& \overset{5}{=} \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } m = n \\ 
0 & \text{ if } m \neq n 
\end{cases}
\end{aligned} $$

Where:

1. Since $ \mathscr{F} \left\{ \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) \right\} = T \, \Pi \left( \frac{ \omega }{ {W}_{s} } \right) {e}^{-j \omega n T} $.
2. Changing order of integration for converging integrals.
3. Applying $ \mathscr{F} \left\{ \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - m T }{T} \right) \right\} \left( - \omega\right) $.
4. Integration boundaries according to the Rect function (Multiplication).
5. Integration over a cycle or over a constant.

Since we proved the suggested base is indeed an orthonormal basis of the space the following holds:

$$ \forall f \left( x \right) \in \mathcal{B}_{{W}_{s}} , \; f \left( x \right) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n} \langle f \left( x \right), {g}_{n} \left( x \right) \rangle {g}_{n} \left( x \right) $$

Where $ {g}_{n} \left( x \right) = \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) $ and $ \langle f \left( x \right), {g}_{n} \left( x \right) \rangle $ is the projection of $ f \left( x \right) $ on $ {g}_{n} \left( x \right) $.

#### Projection Process

As written above, using the result of a projection of a function in the space onto the basis one could reconstruct it as:

$$ f \left( x \right) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n} \langle f \left( x \right), {g}_{n} \left( x \right) \rangle {g}_{n} \left( x \right) $$

The question is, what's is the projection of a general function in this space? Well, it turns out it can be shown in a sloed form way:

$$ \begin{aligned}
\langle f \left( x \right), {g}_{n} \left( x \right) \rangle & = \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f \left( x \right) {g}_{n} \left( x \right) dx = \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f \left( x \right) \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) dx && \text{} \\
& \overset{1}{=} \frac{1}{T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F \left( \omega \right) {e}^{j \omega x} d\omega \right) \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) dx && \text{} \\
& \overset{2}{=} \frac{1}{2 \pi T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) {e}^{j \omega x} dx \right) F \left( \omega \right) d\omega && \text{} \\
& \overset{3}{=} \frac{1}{2 \pi T} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} T \, \Pi \left( \frac{-\omega}{ {W}_{s} } \right) {e}^{j \omega n T} {F} \left( \omega \right) d\omega && \text{} \\
& \overset{4}{=} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{ - \frac{ {W}_{s} }{2} }^{ \frac{ {W}_{s} }{2} } F \left( \omega \right) {e}^{j \omega n T} d\omega && \text{} \\
& \overset{5}{=} f \left( n T \right)
\end{aligned} $$

Where:

1. Since $ \mathscr{F} \left\{ f \left( x \right) \right\} = F \left( \omega \right) $.
2. Changing order of integration for converging integrals.
3. Applying $ \mathscr{F} \left\{ \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - m T }{T} \right) \right\} \left( -\omega \right) $.
4. Integration boundaries according to the Rect function.
5. Applying Inverse Fourier Transform at $ x = n T $.

Wrapping it yields:

$$ f \left( x \right) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{n} \langle f \left( x \right), {g}_{n} \left( x \right) \rangle {g}_{n} \left( x \right) = \sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty} f \left( n T \right) \operatorname{sinc} \left( \frac{ x - n T }{T} \right) $$

Which is known as the [Whittaker Shannon Interpolation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula).

### Conclusion

In the process above the analysis and synthesis of *Band Limited Functions* is shown using Orthonormal Basis. If one set $ T $ to be the *Sampling Interval*, usually denoted by $ {T}_{s} $ then the *Sampling Frequency* is given by $ {F}_{s} = \frac{1}{ {T}_{s} } $.
Now, since the function in frequency domain stretches in the range $ \left[ -\frac{{F}_{s}}{2}, \frac{{F}_{s}}{2} \right] $ we indeed have the known relation that the sampling frequency has to be twice the one sided support of the function in frequency.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your lengthy answer, I will accept it. It is telling me I have to wait 17 hours.

Comment: @deerclaysup, You're welcome. It's a really nice approach to the subject.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson, Thank you for the useful edit.

Comment: looks like i missed one.